# Uso correcto de JDialog

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy trabajando con Swing en Java, en concreto con los JDialog.

Lo que quiero saber es si estoy haciendo un buen uso del JDialog, en concreto el hecho de 'cerrar' y 'abrir' el dialogo.

Código->

```
public class EJ5 extends JFrame{
    
    private MyDialog mydialog;
    
    public EJ5() {
        mydialog = new MyDialog(this,true);
        this.initGUI();
    }
    
    private void initGUI() {
        this.setLocation(200,200);

        ...

        JButton boton = new JButton("Open Modal");
        JFrame self = this;
        
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((EJ5) self).mydialog.showDialog();
            }   
        });
        
        ...

    }
    
    public static class MyDialog extends JDialog{
        
        public MyDialog(JFrame father, boolean modal) {
            super(father,modal);
            this.initGUI();
        }
        
        private void initGUI() {
            this.setLocation(400,200);

            ...

            JButton boton = new JButton("Close");
            JDialog self = this;
            
            boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ((MyDialog) self).closeDialog();
                }
                
            });

            ...
        }
                
        public void showDialog() {
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        public void closeDialog() {
            this.dispose();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Código completo -> https://paste.ofcode.org/XBws87ipQ4UUbEm8pEhWCp

El programa funciona, el modal se abre y se cierra, el caso es si es una buena manera de hacerlo. Por ejemplo para mostrarlo seteo la propiedad visible, pero para ocultarlo hago dispose (Al ser modal, no me vale que ponga visible a false porque la ventana principal seguira bloqueada, o eso creo...).
Aprovecho para preguntar si la triquiñuela de la variable self es correcta o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente el abrir el JDialog con solamente `setVisible(true)`, eso significa que el JDialog va a estar en memoria mientras se este usando el JFrame ya que lo instanciamos una sola vez, tu programa funciona.

He realizado una prueba.

1.- Instancie 10000 veces JDialog y le puse `setVisible(true)` y luego `dispose()` después de realizar esto hubo un consumo de memoria RAM de 1.100 MB lo que implica más de 1GB de memoria.

```
AddCustomerDialog dialog;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    dialog=new AddCustomerDialog();     
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
}
```

2.- Como segundo paso realice una comprobación solo instanciada una vez y luego recorrí el for mostrando y cerrando el JDialog, en este apenas al iniciar el frame ya hubo un consumo de 5MB más, pero una vez ejecutado el código 10000 veces hubo un consumo de 64 MB y si sumamos lo del inicio del programa tenemos 70MB redondeando.

```
AddCustomerDialog dialog= new AddCustomerDialog();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {               
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
}
```

3. Para este tercer paso realice una comprobación extra e hice que se declarará la variable del JDialog  dentro del bucle y hubo un consumo de memoria aproximado de unos 80MB.

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        AddCustomerDialog dialog = new AddCustomerDialog();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
   ```

**CONCLUSIÓN:** Si vas a necesitar abrir y cerrar el JDialog con demasiada frecuencia es mejor solo instanciarlo una vez y utilizar el `setVisible(true)` y `dispose()`, en este caso te aconsejo utilizarlo como en el punto 2. Sin embargo si por ejemplo solo lo vas a usar una vez es mejor instanciarlo para que el recolector de basura haga su trabajo después; aunque el recolector de basura haría mejor su trabajo si no lo instanciamos como el ejemplo en el punto 1 ya que es demasiado rápido.
Se añadió el punto 3 y vemos que al finalizar el bloque se hace elegible por el recolector de basura, por lo que la mejor manera es instanciarlo cada vez que se requiera y el consumo de memoria es muy parecido al punto 2.

Por otro lado lo que haces al decir

```
JFrame self=this;
```

Simplemente le dices al programa que apunte a la dirección de memoria del JFrame, esto puedes setearlo una única vez.

Comment: *Lo que debes hacer es instanciar cada vez que lo vas a abrir* -> Si utilizas mucho un JDialog y estás constantemente usando `dispose()` y creando uno nuevo estás generando más carga que reusando uno a base de mostrarlo y ocultarlo. Y dado que está reutilizándolo es muy poco probable que tenga más de 1 en cualquier momento, sobre todo porque es algo que se muestra fisicamente al usuario.

Comment: Exacto a eso me refiero si no tienes demasiados JDialog no hay problema. Pero también hay que tener en cuenta que Java tiene un recolector de basura muy maduro y funciona bien con varias instancias.

Comment: He realizado una pequeña prueba, le voy a agregar a la respuesta.